# matplotlib code does not shows anything on output

Tags: matplotlib

I am following this here: https://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html

The code is this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

img = mpimg.imread('1.jpg')
```

I am trying to output something, but when I execute the code, I get nothing... Shouldn't I get a matrix as output?

Comment: add `img` at the end of the script

Comment: Ok, I tried but the same. The code is executed without errors, and nothing seen on output.

Comment: Well, it depends on where you run this code. Usually to produce output in python you need to `print` it, i.e. `print(img)`

Comment: Best always refer to the [current version](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/images.html) in the documentation. There the code has the print function included.

Comment: Generally where should I run the maplotlib code?

Comment: No, one cannot say where you *should* run the code. It totally depends on what you're doing and with what aim.

Comment: I am trying to learn basic steps of CNN where matplotlib is used, I have seen 2-3 different tutorials, but the code is never run correctly and I am wondering why. I tried update matplotlib but without success

Comment: I result in that matplotlib GUI does not work on the Ubuntu I have. I am trying three days to build a Convolution Neural Network and make it work, but I have faced many problems with matplotlib. Here it says: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/images.html to run matplotlib inline command. I run it it, but I get the below errors:>>> matplotlib inline
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    matplotlib inline
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> %matplotlib inline
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    %matplotlib inline
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax